# IntroJs Before starting the introJs I can't to go specific step

Tags: intro.js

```
introJs().goToStep(2).start(); //starts introduction from step 2
```

for some reason this one doesn't work from documentation

```
  if (guideInProgress !== null) {
                        intro.goToStep(guideInProgress); // Go to the stored step
                    } else {
                        intro.goToStep(0); // Start from the first step if no progress is stored
                    }
                    intro.start(function () {

                    });
```

When initialy started the introjs the gotostep does not work but if it inside a onexit it work normally.